# No element "ffmpegcolorspace" in GStreamer

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp

While executing the following command,

> gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=Wildlife.wmv ! decodebin ! queue ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink dec. ! queue ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink

I Get the error as follows.

```
ERROR GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:716:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: no element "ffmpegcolorspace"
ERROR GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:801:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: link has no sink [source=@0000000003066F90] 
ERROR GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:801:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: link has no source [sink=@000000000306B060]
ERROR GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:1138:priv_gst_parse_launch: No src-element named "dec" - omitting link
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "ffmpegcolorspace"
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A few things:

In gstreamer-1.0, `ffmpegcolorspace` was renamed to `videoconvert`.
You need to give your decodebin the name you want to refer to it later. Add `name=dec` to be able to refer to it when linking the audio branch.

Also, you might want to consider just using `playbin` if you just need playback. It will assemble the pipeline for you and will support multiple formats automatically.

Comment: gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=Wildlife.wmv ! decodebin name=dec ! queue ! videoconvert ! autovideosink dec. ! queue ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink